# Data Binding Exception With @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble binding values to a Drop Down List.

**Model**

```
public class DummyModel
{
    ...
    public int? OptionID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Line In View Causing Exception**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OptionID, new SelectList(ViewBag.AvailableOptions, "ID", "Name"))
```

**The Contents of the ViewBag**

```
?ViewBag.AvailableOptions
Count = 4
    [0]: {[3, Average Speed]}
    [1]: {[4, Snails pace]}
    [2]: {[1, Super Fast]}
    [3]: {[2, Super Slow]}
```

**The exception that gets generated:**

> System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Comment: Please add the action code so that we can see what you are assigning to `ViewBag.AvailableOptions`

Comment: What type is in `ViewBag.AvailableOptions` ?

Comment: The type appears to be a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as mentioned in the comments / from the text of the exception), `ViewBag.AvailableOptions` is a dictionary you'll want to change the Id and Value properties of your select list like so :

```
new SelectList(ViewBag.AvailableOptions, "Key", "Value")
```

Since a dictionary is basically a list of `KeyValuePair` objects when enumerated, its properties are (as one could imagine) `Key` and `Value`.

Comment: Thank you Francis! This works the way I would expect.